# Angular directive scope between google maps and a controller

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, controller, scope, directive

The following code finds the current users iPhone geolocation on load and loads a google map accordingly using a directive.

Unfortunately the geolocationData data variable from the directive does not get shared to the html footer {{geolocationData}}...

So how can I pass in this case the geolocationData across from the directive to the html page and/or the controller.

Thank you.

Directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp.directives', ['ngCordova'])

.directive('map', function($cordovaGeolocation) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      onCreate: '&'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
      function initialize() {
      if ( !$scope.geolocationData ) {
        $scope.geolocationData = {};
      }

      $cordovaGeolocation
        .getCurrentPosition()
        .then(function (position) {
          var lat  = position.coords.latitude
          $scope.geolocationData.latitude = lat;
          var long = position.coords.longitude
          $scope.geolocationData.longitude = long;

          console.log("POSITION: ", lat, long); //works

          var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            // center: $scope.geolocationCenter,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);

          $scope.onCreate({map: map});

          // Stop the side bar from dragging when mousedown/tapdown on the map
          google.maps.event.addDomListener($element[0], 'mousedown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          });

        }, function(err) {
          // error
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }
  };
});
```

And the following controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $cordovaGeolocation) {

  if ( !$scope.geolocationData ) {
    $scope.geolocationData = {};
  }
};
```

And the following html snippet:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">

  <!-- MAP AREA -->
  <ion-content scroll="false" style="bottom:50%;">
    <map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
    {{geolocationData}}
  </ion-footer-bar>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is.

On the directive side you use:

```
$scope.onCreate({map: map, geolocationData: geolocationData});
```

And then you pass it in your HTML and retrieve it in your controller :)

Scripts bellow...

HTML:

```
...
<ion-content scroll="false" style="bottom:50%;">
  <map on-create="mapCreated(map, geolocationData)"></map>
</ion-content>
...
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
...
$cordovaGeolocation
  .getCurrentPosition()
  .then(function (position) {
    var lat  = position.coords.latitude
    var geolocationData = {};
    geolocationData.latitude = lat;
    var long = position.coords.longitude
    geolocationData.longitude = long;

    console.log("POSITION: ", lat, long);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
      // center: $scope.geolocationCenter,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);

    $scope.onCreate({map: map, geolocationData: geolocationData});
...
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.mapCreated = function(map, geolocationData) {
  $scope.map = map;
  $scope.geolocationData = geolocationData;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

One way is to set data binding between your `MapCtrl` and your directive.

In your directive you have:

```
scope: { geolocation: '=' }
```

In your markup

```
<map on create=".." geolocation-data="geolocationData"><map>
```

The other way is to create a service that holds the data. You can then inject it in both your mapctrl and in you directive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts Gilles. It is always much appreciated. I gave a go to your solution and was not able to make it work so I used the following as a workaround.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. [In the meantime, here's a bin close to your code that illustrate the first option of my response.](http://jsbin.com/qosezuwixa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Strangely enough my solution is still not accurate. I have added a moveable marker and when I do something like marker.getPosition().lat(); from within the Controller, and update the $scope.geolocationData within the scope my Html page does not update the values... even though I can console.log both new lat and log, and the scope.geolocationData... Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Could put that in a jsbin? It'll be easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your response, here is a link to it, please note that I pasted all three file into the JS section... :( http://jsbin.com/luhasa/2/edit?html,js

Comment: I've adapted you bin. Changes on data in the directive are now reflected outside its scope. Note that I use the `templateUrl` attribute in the directive, that the binding of `geolocationData`in the markup is done through `<map ... geolocation-data="geolocationData">`. [check it out here](http://jsbin.com/kirimu/2) It think it answers your original question.